# Is it possible to send POST file to GitLab pipeline job artifact?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-pipelines

I have a pipeline running externally and send the status of the pipeline back to GitLab through GitLab API. I am wondering if it is also possible to send the pipeline logs and store them in the job artifact of GitLab. From what I understand, the artifact seems to be created only via internal (gitlab-ci.yml) and [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#) here does not state any option to create POST to the job artifact as well.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's possible to automate almost anything, so long as it is computable.  There may be restrictions, of course, such as security requirements, disk space and other considerations.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Do you perhaps know any related documentation or example that could achieve such a thing?

Comment: Do you have some code you've already written that we could look at?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not exactly stuck. I successfully send the status to GitLab pipeline via GitLab API [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#:~:text=Post%20the%20build%20status%20to%20a%20commit) but I could not see any option where I can send the log file as an artifact.

Comment: To what end? ...

Comment: So I sent the pipeline status back to GitLab via this `POST /projects/:id/statuses/:sha` and in GitLab, it appears as an external job (doesn't even have job id).

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: What I am looking into right now is this [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#) which states only how to `GET` the artifact from the pipeline and it requires `job_id` (which I don't have bc of the external job). While what I am trying to do is to send file to the pipeline artifact.